# why custom hook , context with useEffect lead to infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect, react-context

why this simple code leads to **infinite loop rendering Projects component** and its child(naturally) and because of useEffect **infinite loop accessing firebase**?
managing state with contextProvider which has imported useProjects custom hook.

custom hook :

```
export const useProjects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const db = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .where("userId", "==", "1234567890")
      .orderBy("projectId")
      .get();
    db.then((result) => {
      const allProjects = result.docs.map((project) => ({
        docId: project.id,
        ...project.data(),
      }));

      if (JSON.stringify(allProjects) !== JSON.stringify(projects)) {
        setProjects(allProjects);
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("useProjects error", err);
    });
  }, [projects]);
  return { projects, setProjects };
};
```

Projects component:

```
const Projects = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);
  const { setSelectedProject } = useSelectedProjectValue();
  const { projects } = useProjectsValue();

  return (
    projects &&
    projects.map((project) => (
      <li
        key={Math.random()}
        className={
          active === project.projectId
            ? "sidebar__project active"
            : "sidebar__project"
        }
      >
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setActive(project.projectId);
            setSelectedProject(project.projectId);
          }}
        >
          <IndividualProject
            className="individualProjectComp"
            project={project}
          />
        </div>
      </li>
    ))
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting projects state within useEffect which takes projects as a dependency itself and even though you are comparing project value before setting, some change while stringifying the value is causing the state update each time.

You can avoid it by not adding projects as a dependency to `useEffect` since `projects` is only being updated inside `useEffect` and not anywhere else

```
export const useProjects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const db = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .where("userId", "==", "1234567890")
      .orderBy("projectId")
      .get();
    db.then((result) => {
      const allProjects = result.docs.map((project) => ({
        docId: project.id,
        ...project.data(),
      }));

      setProjects(allProjects);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("useProjects error", err);
    });
  }, []);
  return { projects, setProjects };
};
```

Comment: tanx a lot , what about the warning it gives me that we better not to use empty square brackets as second argument?

Comment: The ESLint warning is there to prompt you incase you are missing a dependency that you otherwise should have added. however if you are sure what you are doing is right, you can silence the warning. Check this post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902